# .NET Chart control - dynamically change y-axis interval

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-3.5, charts

I have a bar graph displaying a number of different series (stacked on each other) and I'm trying to find a way to dynamically change the y-axis interval if the values go above a set value.

If the bars only go up to a maximum of 50, I'd like the interval to be 25 so the bars still 'look' rather small. But if a large spike comes through, the interval needs to be set to 0 so the large spike is more noticeable.

Oh, and this is in C# .NET 3.5

I hope that makes sense :)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty much feasible by tweaking both the size of the axis and the relative intervals dynamically by updating the right properties. Default control behavior is rescaling the axis to adapt to the dataset so this should be no problem (works well for me)
Take a look at the [Axis Class MSDN Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.axis.aspx), especially the [Interval](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.axis.interval.aspx) and [IntervalAutoMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.axis.intervalautomode.aspx) Properties. (the MSDN in pretty exhaustive on chart control if you dig enough you'll find everything you might need).
 

 besides I HEAVILY advice you to download the very complete [sample application](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart) 
and play around with it locally. It is pretty exhaustive and you'll have the complete source at hand.

Answer (score 0):

Set IntervalAutoMode="Variable Count" and dint mention any axis interval in the Axis Y element of the chart Area of that chart,it will adjust according to the maximum value.